# How to include an external EXE with my code?

Tags: c#

I have a third party program I use that what it does nothing else exists that does this so loading another library or NuGet package directly into Visual Studio 2019 wouldn't be an option.  No DLL's for it or anything. It includes an exe I call with some parameters.  Doing this with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process videoprocess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();  
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo videostartInfo = new  
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo  
  {  
      WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,  
      FileName = "cmd.exe",
```

So after this I call the program and arguments and it does it's thing and I just get back a thumbs up or down.  When I'm done writing this program I will set it up on another computer.  Is there any way to bake in the exe to the program so I can just call the exe without worrying about pathing or making sure I bring it with me to the final computer this code will run on all the time?

Comment: You could just put it in a subfolder of your project yes (along with any other files it needs to work) and then make sure that's included as content in your build. That's assuming it doesn't need any kind of other installation or registration steps before it can be used on a new machine.

Comment: Thanks.  One side thought.  Is there a way to build a NuGet package that would contain the exe or in this case to do it properly contain all the executables in the program I call including python scripts it uses but I don't for my piece.  Just wondering then if it would auto load it in my project and auto show whenever I compile it?

Comment: A nuget package can contain anything, it needn't contain .net code necessarily, so yes there's nothing to stop you in theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the thirdparty executable is already installed on the system, else the exe is included in the output.

In the first case you could simply hardcode a path to `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` (32bit), or really any path you choose.

A company where i work for has control over all systems that run our software and our hierarchy is always as follows:

- Company

  - Software

    - App
  - ThirdParty

    - App1
    - App2

This makes it easy to locate thirdparty software.

Another option is to just include it in the build, so it gets output to the build directory. You can do this by right clicking your project and then doing 'add existing file' and then choose any extension in the file selector popup window.

The exe then gets added as content, and you can set it to 'copy if newer' in the properties tab:
[image]

The csproj file wil look like so:

```xml
    <Content Include="HmiLogViewer.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

You could also try add as link, which will add the file as link:

[image]

```xml
    <Content Include="..\HmiLogViewer\HmiLogViewer\bin\Debug\HmiLogViewer.exe">
      <Link>HmiLogViewer.exe</Link>
    </Content>
```

If you want to add a directory of files, you can also add this piece of xml to the csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistributedFilesFolderFiles Include="..\..\DistributedFiles\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="@(DistributedFilesFolderFiles)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>True</Visible>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Ofcourse adjust the path(s) to your situation.

Edit:

"That said do I need to pass the launch folder of the app as part of calling that exe file or will it automatically look there."

We look for it automatically with the option to override the value from a settings file (you could use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`), for example when we need to test an updated version of the thirdparty exe or when the path has changed.

```cs
public static string ExecutablePathAndFileName { get; } = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
public static string DataDrive { get; } = Path.GetPathRoot(ExecutablePathAndFileName);
public static string ExecutableFolder { get; } = Path.GetDirectoryName(ExecutablePathAndFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks sommmen. This is fantastic. So I'm going to have it copy it into the project folder when compiling. That said do I need to pass the launch folder of the app as part of calling that exe file or will it automatically look there. Like AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: @JoselineRiker see the updated answer. Also - the name Riker keeps reminding me of star trek..